# Android in-app billing on other publisher

Tags: android, billing, in-app

I plan to use in-app billing but the docs say about the limitation.

- In-app billing can be implemented only in applications that you publish through Android Market.

I plan to release my app on publisher sites like Amzaon, getjar etc, in addition to Google Market.

How should I handle in-app billing on these 3rd party publishers? Should I use totally separate code for 3rd party publishers (for purchases)? Seems ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

you can use paypal mpl sdk instead.